# How to set scrollable text view in a TableRow

Tags: android, textview, scroll

I have a textview wrapped in a table row.
The contents of the Textview may take up multiple lines so I am want to make the textview scrollable but with no success.

I have tried via XML and programmatically:

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_Refeeral_Center"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_Referral_Center_Input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:scrollbars = "vertical"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Hours        "
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
```

And in my class I set the movement method of the textview:

referralLabTV.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());

I have also tried by wrapping the textview in a scrollview but also does not work:

```
 <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_RefRanges"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="Ref Ranges"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                 >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrefRanges_Input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"


                android:maxLines="6"

                android:typeface="sans"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Ref Range"
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </ScrollView>
        </TableRow>
```

Any input appreciated.

@Shagar

I tried your solution but still the same, can olnlt see first line of text that is added from database to the textview programmatically. This is the entire Linear/table layout

```
TableLayout 
             android:id="@+id/testSelcted_tabl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_selectedTest_Section2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"

             >

             <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_TAT"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="TAT (hrs)"
                 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_TATText"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:scrollbars = "vertical"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Contact Referral Lab"
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>


             <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_Fixation"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="Fixation"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTFixation_Input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Histology"
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
              <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_TATUrgent"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="Urgent"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_TATUrgetInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Hours        "
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow> 
               <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_Refeeral_Center"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="Referral Lab"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_Referral_Center_Input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:scrollbars = "vertical"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Hours        "
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

               <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable_RefRanges"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:text="Ref Ranges"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <!-- wrap a linear layout in a scroll voew which wraps the textview fro textview to scroll -->

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shaoe"
                 >
                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrefRanges_Input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Ref Range"
                android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="jwwhegfrhegihsighhgishgifhwihgawihrgaiwhgihigheihgraiehrgiher"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </TableRow>

         </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could do this is change textview to a editview with attributes:

android:editable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a LinearLayout inside of your ScrollView.
and make your TextView height witdh matched to its parent.
here is the modified code.

```
 <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            >
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvrefRanges_Input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:maxLines="6"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Ref Range"
                    android:textColor="#c4c4c4"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Hello\nHello\nHello\nHello\nHello\nHello\nHello\n"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yep tried that still the same....have a look at the edit above i have added your code...the table layout is wrapped in a linear layout also